# How to create custom shape with animation in Android

Tags: android

In my application I want create shape such as below image: 
[image] 
With this link you can see this shape animation: [See shape animation](https://streamable.com/jjx57q)

I search many times in google, github and I know I can create this with canvas. 
But I don't any thing from canvas and my time is very I can't read canvas from zero!

How can I create this? Or can you suggest to me for other ways for create this shape?

Answer (score 0):

Use AnimationDrawable
Checkout this linkL:
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/animations/drawable-animation

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the answer with all relevant information. Make sure to use your own words, [answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content.](/help/referencing).